# c# WebClient does not post my location information

Tags: c#, google-maps, geolocation, location, webclient

I use Google GeoCoding API from a c# WebClient Object.

The url returns almost the same Address Information as it does in the browser -
only some names are different like Street, Path, Alley in place of Strasse, Weg, Gasse.

The issue is that the browser DOES send its Location 
to the Google Geocoding API and so the browser does retrieve german names.

On the other hand the c# WebClient evidently DOES NOT send its 
actual Location to the Google Geocoding API and so it retrieves english names.

How can I make the c# WebClient behave like a browser does 
and make it send its actual location to the Web Server ?

thanks 
Gerald

Comment: Can you add some code please? Which version are you using - v3? If you are using v3 you could try setting the optional `region` parameter to `de` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRegionCodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `AcceptLanguage` header:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "de");
// Do the rest of your request.
```

Comment: for some reason this header information is ignored by the Google API

Comment: OOPS - VERY SORRY - IT DOES WORK!
I had a coding error while I tested this solution.
Many thanks for your advise!